# Wix bootstrapper not displaying internal ui

Tags: wix

I have a Wix bootstrapper project chaining two msi packages. I need to display UI from both the msi files during installation. I have DisplayInternalUI set to yes on both of them. But when I install I don't see any UI. Am I missing something?

```
  <MsiPackage Id="SqlXml" SourceFile="c:/installables/sqlxml-64.msi" Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes"></MsiPackage>
  <MsiPackage Id="MyProgram" SourceFile="c:/installables/MyProgram.msi" Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes"></MsiPackage>
```

Comment: Did you by any change find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem at the moment.